# Designing class structure of Spring based kafka listener/producer

Tags: java, oop, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have to write multiple listeners which will all listen to different topics. Once they receive the message, the will be applying their specific business logic and then they will be publishing the result to `TopicX`.

From oop perspective, how i had thought about it is something like

```
@Service
public abstract class MessageGenerator {   
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Value("${app.topic.result}")
    private String topic;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${app.kafka.incoming.topicOne}")
    public void listen(@Payload String message) {
        String msgToBePublished = applyBusinessLogic(message);
        kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message);
    }

    public abstract String applyBusinessLogic(message);
}
```

My idea was that i will create this base class and then implement the specific business logic. By doing so, i would take care a redundant kafka related message receiving/sending code.

Given that each implementation will have a different `incoming.topicX` to listen on, I am not sure how can i implement it in proper OOP way. Some ways i can think of

- Shall i keep `listen` method exclusive to specific implementations?
- Instead of creating inheritance model. I can create a generic `sender` class with `kafkaTemplate`. Each `businesslogic` class will have this `sender` class in it to publish messages.

What do you guys suggest.